# Libgdx, how to access callbacks inside 'implemented interface'

Tags: android, interface, callback, libgdx

I need to implement a LibGDX project with WS (websockets). androidAsync seems to be a good one.

However I am stuck on Both the solutions I have thought.

One : Is that I use core module (Common for Desktop,Android,IOS etc) . Call all AA functions there. But It doesn't Compile. It seems to require Android.net.uri or something inside which isn't available to core module.

Two : Is that I do Android Specific only. According to LibGDX , I do that through Interface . Now I implement the interface but Guess what There will be callback Inside Interface, which I am Unable to use. Future with blocking can be used with a return statement but I can't seem to find blocking call for WS because by design it relies on event callbacks. The code implemented in Android Module for corresponding core module interface.

```
@Override
public String getStringNonAsync(String url)
        throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Future<String> stringFuture = AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().executeString(
        new AsyncHttpGet(url), new AsyncHttpClient.StringCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, AsyncHttpResponse source, String result) {

            }
        }
    );
    Log.d("Android", "Interfce called");
    return stringFuture.get();
}
```

How do I get the result string from on completed callback rather than a blocking call to get().

The code calling This in Core Module. asyncInterface is the interface implemented in all other modules. I have no way to retrieve the call backs , only return statements (As far as I can think).

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Tap = game.asyncInterface.getStringNonAsync(Url);
//todo set the string, onRender().
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: What's preventing you from calling a method in your game class from the `onCompleted` method?

Comment: It's the Dependency of the library... Doesn't compile. Hence I cannot use androidasync.. Android only has starter class that I can use where I pass an implementation of the interface new someclassthatinplementstheinterface(). Then I encounter the callbacks which can't seem to be accessed.

Comment: I don't follow. In the code you posted, it looks like your AA library is only in the Android project and the only thing left for you to do is to put something in the onCompleted method that calls code in your core project.

Comment: Yes it's on android project only.. It doesn't compile if I add it to core. If it ran in core project it would be painless.. That is why I have to implement the interface in android and call it from core.

Comment: Reread my last comment. I think you are line away from being done.